# SELECT Min And Max values not associated with same record

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery, greatest-n-per-group

I have a simple MS Access database with the sales records of several items aggregated by various time intervals (expressed in months). This information is the result of a query based on daily sales figures (it just aggregates sales by months). A simplified view of the main table is appended below.

[image]

I have a problem and could not figure it out even after searching for quite a while. Take item A for example: the table shows that, in the past 1 month, it sold 10 units while in the past 2 months it sold 30 units. Since this item does not have sales recorded for periods like 3 months or 4 months, it means it was introduced in the system 2 months ago. It is easy to write a query to get max(quantity) and its associated sales interval (2 months) because the max value is only one, namely 30.

But look at item B. This item  sold 50 units in the past 3 months and also 50 units in the past 4 months (this means that either the item was introduced in the system 4 months ago and sold nothing over the period t-4 to t-3 months, or it means it was introduced in the system only 3 months ago and appears with sales over the past 4 months because it did sell 50 units in the past 3 months, which are part of the "last 4 months" interval (a result of the data structure of the table).

How can I get max(quantity)=50 associated with min(interval)=3?

If I try:

```
SELECT [MODEL ID],MAX([QUANTITY]), MIN([INTERVAL]) 
FROM [TABLE X]
GROUP BY [MODEL ID]
```

Then of course I get, for item B,  max sold=50 and interval = 1 month (the shortest interval), but what need is max(quantity) associated with min(3,4), so 50 and 3 months.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In MS Access, we could try and approach this with a `TOP 1` correlated subquery:

```
select x.*
from [TABLE X] as x
where x.[INTERVAL] in (
    select TOP 1 x1.[INTERVAL]
    from [TABLE X] as x1
    where x1.[MODEL ID] = x.[MODEL ID]
    order by x1.[QUANTITY] desc, x1.[INTERVAL]
)
order by x.[MODEL ID]
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this solution, going through the syntax very very carefully but I got an error: "At most one record can be returned by this subquery"...still lost here...

Comment: @StefanLiiceanu: I don't think that this query can raise this error - maybe you forgot the `TOP 1` clause in the subquery?

Comment: As I said, I typed the query with maximum care, did not miss a single character. But I think the error may arise from the fact that the table contains items that have only one record, in which case, maybe TOP 1 with one record results in that error. I will try on a hypothetical table.

Comment: @StefanLiiceanu: does in work better with `in` instead of `=`? I changed the query in my answer.

Comment: I tried this too. It did not give an error, but the processing time was too long...it looked like it would never finish, so I had to kill the routine. I will keep trying, I will figure it out and come back with a solution. All the best!